# What does "Compression Method : null(0)" mean in Client Hello?

Tags: 14.04, networking, compression, wireshark, packet-analyzer

As a task of my assignment, I used wireshark to capture packets. Now in Client Hello message, I saw `compression method:null(0)`. Now I am confused what is that mean? Does that mean no compression is required? Or `null(0)` is itself a compression technique?

[image: Click Here to see the image of compression method:null(0).]

Comment: What traffic are you investigating?

Comment: investigating gmail

Answer (score 0):

See [section 6.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.2) and [section 7.4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) of [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246).

Answer (score 0):

Compression method: null (0) means that the data received from the record layer will not be compressed, nowadays SSL is not doing the compression for the data received from the upper layer because HTTP is doing the job for it at layer 7.

So usually, you will find this to be set as null.